# The construction and etymology of -たら

Tags: grammar, translation, etymology, conditionals

Ever since I learned that "if" and "when" can be used as translations for the -たら conditional form depending on the context, I have been looking for an explanation of its construction in terms of its etymology to have a proper understanding of how it works. The sources I have looked up say that it is formed from the "past tense" -た form + ら, but I have failed to find any information on this ら. Is it a classical Japanese auxiliary verb? Is the full form -たらば? Does it have anything to do with the 連体形 or attributive form of classical verb ending ～たり? Or is -たら the 仮定形 form of -た?

Please enlighten me on this topic so that I can stop translating this expression to English and start seeing it in terms of Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

As regards the grammar of the modern Japanese, it is 仮定形<sup>1</sup> of [た](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9F/#jn-132183), auxiliary verb meaning past tense. At the same time, the standard etymology says た derives from たり<sup>2</sup>, so your guess is not totally off.

> ［助動］［たろ｜○｜た｜た｜**たら<sup>1</sup>**｜○］**《助動詞「たり」の連体形「たる」の音変化<sup>2</sup>》**活用語の連用形に付く。連用形が撥音便、およびガ行がイ音便となる場合には連濁で「だ」となる。

What is a little irregular about たら are:

1. It can be used without ば, unlike most other 仮定形: The linked dictionary entry notes 仮定形「たら」は、多く「**ば」を伴わないで**「雨が降ったら中止だ」などと使われ、「遅いからもう帰ったら」のように文末に用いられて8の意を表す。
2. For 仮定形, you may expect e-sound, i.e. たれ. But it retains classical 未然形: [Wikipedia/已然形](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B7%B2%E7%84%B6%E5%BD%A2) notes 形容動詞とコピュラ「だ」、「た」だけは仮定条件の「ば」の前が未然形である**文語の形式を残している**ため「なら」、「たら<sup>3</sup>」になっている。

たら<sup>3</sup> refers to the (classical) 未然形 of [たり](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A):

> ［助動］［**たら<sup>3</sup>**｜たり｜たり｜たる｜たれ｜たれ］《完了の助動詞「つ」の連用形に動詞「あり」の付いた「てあり」の音変化》ラ変以外の動詞、および動詞型活用の助動詞の連用形に付く。
>
> [補説] 中世以降は...「たる」を経て現代語の「た」に引き継がれる。

Comment: A concern about the Goo entry is that the part of speech for all of these, and indeed the usage examples, are none of them for mid-sentence conditional ～たら. The derivation given in the Goo entry is ultimately from といったら, whereas the derivation of the conditional ～たら is from ～て + あらば. This ～てあらば construction can be seen in the [_Man'yōshū_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man'y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB), such as [book 4, poem 581](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man4Yos.html#581), or [book 11, poem 2419](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man11Yo.html#2419).

Comment: Separately, you wrote that _"た, auxiliary verb meaning **passive**."_ Surely you meant _"**past tense**"_ instead?  The Goo entry itself says 『過去の助動詞「た」』.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thanks, I meant to link to た.